# How do I parse an input JSON, and based on the existing JSON, which represents a product inventory, generate the bill

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse JSON using GSON library.
I have a product inventory in the form of a JSON like this:

```
[
 {
   "id": 2000,
   "name": "Child Shoes",
   "variants": [
     {
       "size": "size 7",
       "price": 19.99,
       "tax_code": 0
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 3000,
   "name": "Eggs",
   "variants": [
     {
       "size": "6",
       "price": 1.50,
       "tax_code": 7
     },
     {
       "size": "12",
       "price": 2.25,
       "tax_code": 1
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 3100,
   "name": "Apples",
   "variants": [
     {
       "size": "1",
   "price": 0.30,
   "tax_code": 7
 },
 {
   "size": "10",
   "price": 2.50,
   "tax_code": 7
 }
 ]
 },
 {
   "id": 5423,
   "name": "Book",
   "variants": [
     {
       "size": "Assorted",
       "price": 11.00,
       "tax_code": 1
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

And Tax codes as follows :

```
[
 {
   "code": 0,
   "name": "HST",
   "rate": 0.13
 },
 {
   "code": 1,
   "name": "HST - Books",
   "rate": 0.05
 },
 {
   "code": 7,
   "name": "EXEMPT - Food",
   "rate": 0
 }
]
```

Now, how do I generate the total bill, if I get an input like this:

```
[
 {
   "product": 3000,
   "variant": 1,
   "quantity": 1
 },
 {
   "product": 3100,
   "variant": 1,
   "quantity": 1
 }
]
```

I am new to JSON and having a tough time trying to identify the correct strategy to solve this problem.

Comment: You are asking several questions here, how to design your software, how to parse json and possibly also how to program java. You need to focus on one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below solution give you some idea -

Map your json to pojo like below  -

```
 public class ProductInventory {

        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private List<Variant> variants = null;

        public Integer getId() {
        return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
        return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Variant> getVariants() {
        return variants;
        }

        public void setVariants(List<Variant> variants) {
        this.variants = variants;
        }
        }

    //class Variant
        public class Variant {

        private String size;
        private Double price;
        private Integer taxCode;

        public String getSize() {
        return size;
        }

        public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
        }

        public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
        }

        public Integer getTaxCode() {
        return taxCode;
        }

        public void setTaxCode(Integer taxCode) {
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        }           
        }
```

Use Gson library to parse json into java object and vice-versa:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type jsonType = new TypeToken<List<ProductInventory>>(){}.getType();
List<ProductInventory> piList = gson.fromJson(json, jsonType);
```

Now Iterate over the `piList` and populate your other pojos and parse it into json using `toJson()` method.

**Note**:- You have to create pojo classes for the target json, that you can create here - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/